# How can i connect these nodes as a directed graph?

Tags: c++, graph

How can i connect these nodes as a directed graph using vectors? Also how can i make it go through each edges only once (Eulerian circuit).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class node
{
     public:
     string a;
     vector<node> connect;
     node(string b)
     {
          a = b;
     }
};

int main()
{
    vector<node> AllNodes;                 
    AllNodes.push_back(A); 
    AllNodes.push_back(B);
    AllNodes.push_back(C);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that, add the connection to the node by using address reference

```
class node
{
public:
    string a;
    vector<node> connect;
    node(string b)
    {
        a = b;
    }

    void add_connect(node &n)
    {
        connect.push_back(n);
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "value: " << a << endl;
    }

    void print_connection()
    {
        for each (node var in connect)
        {
            cout << "conection of " << a << ": ";
            var.print();
        }
    }
};


    int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    node A("A"),B("B"), C("C");
    vector<node> AllNodes;
    AllNodes.push_back(A);
    AllNodes.push_back(B);
    AllNodes.push_back(C);

    A.add_connect(B);
    B.add_connect(C);

    A.print();
    A.print_connection();

    B.print();
    B.print_connection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For making edges, you need edgelist for each node. You already have that in `conncection` member of `class node`.

You just need to add into the list. So, you can just do the following:

```
A.connection.push_back(required_node);
```

It will be better if you hold a reference than a copy of an object. It will save memory.
So, you can define a member function around this logic.

Comment: so basically if i wanted to connect node A and B  i would just do `A.connect.push_back(B);`